# unable to refer to table alias within a nested query

Tags: sql, oracle

The title may seem a little confusing , however the query  may help in understanding my dilemma.
I have a query like this

```
 SELECT TAB1.USER_ID,
        (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(B.COL1, '/'))
           FROM (SELECT A.COL1,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.COL1) AS curr,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.COL1) - 1 AS prev
                   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TAB2.COL1
                           FROM TABLE2 TAB2
                          WHERE TAB2.USER_ID = TAB1.USER_ID) A) B
         CONNECT BY PRIOR curr = prev
          START WITH curr = 1)
   FROM TABL1 TAB1
  WHERE TAB1.REC_STATUS = 'L'
```

I have 2 tables TABLE1 & TABLE2. Both of them have a common attribute, USER_ID. I am selecting the value based on USER_ID and treating the resultant rows as a table itself( referred to as A). However the query fails to take reference of TABLE1 that is created outside A.
This query actually concatenates all the all the COL1 values returned which match the USER_ID condition. As I am using Oracle 9i, the only string concatenation available is WM_CONCAT. I have been told to not use it as this function is undocumented.

Please help as to how I may be able to refer to TAB1's columns(in this case USER_ID) inside the A block.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way.

Sub queries cannot take reference of outer query. Only Nested queries( e.g. create with Exists) can use attributes of outer query in inner query.

example to use outer parameter in inner query.

```
SELECT * FROM R S WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM R WHERE R.a = S.a)
```